# C programming print a certain amount of bytes to screen

Tags: c, file

How can I make the program read "partSize" amount of bytes and print it to the screen? Let's say that I am opening a text file that contains 100 characters in total. If partSize is 50 Bytes, I would expect 50 characters to be printed to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <errno.h>

#define PERMS 0777

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int createDescriptor;
    int openDescriptorOriginal;
    int closeCreateDescriptor;

    //char fileNameOriginal[] = "picture.jpg";
    char fileNameOriginal[] = "myFile.txt";

    int parts;
    int partSize;

    parts=2;

    int bytesRemaining;
    int partNumber;
    char BUFFER[512];
    int readDescriptor;

    if ((openDescriptorOriginal = open(fileNameOriginal, O_RDONLY )) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error opening %s", fileNameOriginal);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct stat buf;
    int r = fstat(openDescriptorOriginal, &buf);
    if (r)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: fstat: %s\n", (char *) strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    int originalFileSize = buf.st_size;
    printf("The file is %.9f Kilobytes large.\n", (double) originalFileSize/1024);

    partSize = ((originalFileSize + parts) + 1)/parts;

    //I am stuck at this part
    while ((readDescriptor = read(openDescriptorOriginal, BUFFER, partSize)) < partSize))
    {
        write(1, BUFFER, readDescriptor);
    }

    if ((closeCreateDescriptor = close(openDescriptorOriginal)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error closing file.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use smaller identifiers. `openDescriptorOriginal` quickly becomes unwieldy.

Comment: Is the value of partSize what you expect? Have you debugged your program? It seems the read/write bit is correct(although readDescriptor is quite misleading for what you use it).

Comment: Yes, partSize seems to be the correct value.

Comment: Are all the characters in the file you read displayable? Also do you get more or less symbols then expected?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on a text file. My text file has 67 characters, partSize is 2. So, 34 chars should be printed out. All 67 get printed out.

Comment: You might like to compile your sources using the options `-Wall -g`, fix all warnings, anf then learn and use `gdb` to trace and debug your program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C programming print a certain amount of bytes to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129648/c-programming-print-a-certain-amount-of-bytes-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the return value, and update the length in each iteration:

```
ssize_t count, total;
total = 0;
char *buf = BUFFER;
while (partSize) {
    count = read(openDescriptorOriginal, buf, partSize);
    if (count < 0) {
        /* handle error */
        break;
    }
    if (count == 0)
        break;
    buf += count;
    total += count;
    partSize -= count;
}
write (1, BUFFER, total);
```

`total` will contain the number of bytes read.