# C programming print a certain amount of bytes to file

Tags: c, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming print a certain amount of bytes to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119354/c-programming-print-a-certain-amount-of-bytes-to-screen)

I would like to read partSize amount of bytes from one file, which can be of any type, and print that same exact amount that was read to a new file which already exists. The program I wrote seems to write less than it is suppose to and gives a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#define PERMS 0777
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{

int createDescriptor;
int openDescriptorOriginal;

int closeCreateDescriptor;

char fileNameOriginal[15]="picture.jpg";
//char fileNameOriginal[15]="myFile.txt";
//char fileNameNew[15]="NEWFILE.txt";
char fileName[15]="NEWFILE.jpg";

int parts;
int partSize;

parts=2;

int bytesRemaining;
int partNumber;

char BUFFER[512];

int readDescriptor;

int openDescriptor;

if ((openDescriptorOriginal = open(fileNameOriginal, O_RDONLY )) == -1)
 {
 printf("Error opening %s", fileNameOriginal);
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

struct stat buf;
int r = fstat(openDescriptorOriginal, &buf);
if(r)
{
fprintf(stderr, "error: fstat: %s\n",(char *)strerror(errno));

exit(1);
}

int originalFileSize=buf.st_size;

printf("The file is %d Bytes large.\n",originalFileSize);

partSize=((originalFileSize+parts)-1)/parts;
printf("Each part is %.9f Kilobytes large.\n",(double)partSize/1024 );


partNumber=1;
printf("Part number: %d\n", partNumber);

if ((openDescriptor = open(fileName, O_WRONLY )) == -1)
{
printf("Error creating %s\n", fileName);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
ssize_t count, total;
total = 0;
char *bufff = BUFFER;
while (partSize) {
   count = read(openDescriptorOriginal, bufff, partSize);
    if (count < 0) {
       // handle error
        break;
    }
    if (count == 0)
        break;
    bufff += count;
    total += count;
    partSize -= count;
}
write (openDescriptor, BUFFER, total);
printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `write()` function has a return value that you don't seem to be examining. Also if your input file is over 512 bytes large, it appears you will be overflowing your `BUFFER`.

Comment: Please indent your wall of code if you want us to study it

Comment: @mah I don't understand how big should I make the buffer?

Comment: @John if you leave your code structure as you've provided it, the buffer must be large enough to hold the largest file you ever deal with. That probably isn't what you want though; with a restructuring (move the position of your `write()` call to be inside the same loop that holds the `read()`) you can use any size buffer you like (as long as you re-use the buffer with each read() call, rather than advancing beyond it the way you currently are).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did ALT + k, how would you prefer I indent it?

Comment: @PaulR It is not a duplicate, I posted that question yesterday.

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How do I indent code properly?

Comment: So, DavidHeffernan's only contribution to this post was telling someone to indent their code, and not even telling them how when nicely asked?

Answer (score 0):

Some initial problems:

- add the CREAT flag to your open() in case the file isn't there.
- partSize should not be adjusted

Take out the line where you adjust partSize and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int bytesReceived;
.... open files ....
while ((bytesReceived = read(openDescriptorOriginal, BUFFER, sizeof(BUFFER)) > 0) {
    if (bytesReceived != write(openDescriptor, BUFFER, bytesReceived) {
        printError(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more explicit, code sample alone is hard to understand.

Comment: If I understand this code correctly, it copies while bytesReceived is greater than 0. bytesReceived will be 0 when it reaches EOF and -1 when there is an error. This is incorrect. If we read the original file until it reaches end of file then we will read the whole file. I want to read partSize amount of bytes, not the whole file.

Comment: @John You're correct that I made the loop read the whole file. I am sure you are capable of modifying my sample to include support for limiting the read size while still maintaining the read/write-both-in-the-loop pattern; just include an extra escape clause and replace `sizeof(BUFFER)` in the `read()` with a value that is modified at the end of the loop (to either be `sizeof(BUFFER)` or the smaller amount in the case of the final data.

Comment: @jb which part of it is hard to understand? There isn't much to it and as you can see, the person that asked the question understood it quite well. If you would like explanation of any part of it I'm happy to help, but its a basic "read from source, write to target, repeat until complete" loop.